# Select Whole Line Of Text Regardless Of Cursor Position

Tags: windows, windows-10, text-editing

Is there any windows keyboard shortcut to select a whole line of text regardless of the cursor position? I know of similar commands like CTRL-A for selecting everything, or SHIFT-End/Home for selecting a line but the cursor has to be at the very beginning or end of said line.

Is there any shortcut that will select the whole line while ignoring the current position of the cursor? I might just setup an AutoHotKey script but was curious if there was an existing command

Comment: Here's the AHK script I threw together quickly if anyone wants it:

`^2::
   Send, {Home}{Shift Down}{End}{Shift up}{Ctrl down}c{Ctrl up}
Return`

Comment: Pressing `home` first, then `shift` + `end` should do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't list such a shortcut [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/126449/keyboard-shortcuts-for-windows), so I doubt there is. Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) didn't have one listed (based on a quick page search). Usually I just press Home first, then Shift + End.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of a keyboard shortcut for that.

But, you can do it easily with a mouse, by **triple-clicking** anywhere on the line you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a shortcut:

```
; Alt-A to select the whole line
!a::
Send {Home}
Send +{End}
Return
```